# What additional documents are required for 2nd visit to Singapore on a multiple-entry visa?

Tags: visas, singapore, multiple-entry

I have a multiple-entry visa for Singapore, valid for 2 years. The visa was issued on 20th Nov 2014, and remains valid until 21st November 2016. I have made only one trip, in December 2014.

Do I need to provide any additional documents before I attempt visit Singapore again, using the same visa, in December 2015?
Do I need to produce any more documents than return tickets for getting the immigration pass?

Answer (score 3):

A visa to Singapore is really only an authorization to travel to the entry port of Singapore. After arriving at the [Immigration and Checkpoints Authority](http://www.ica.gov.sg/index.aspx) officer, you'll need to provide documentation they require of you, every time you visit. The documentary evidence required is the same for every trip. What you needed to take and show the first trip, you will need to take and show the second trip, i.e.,

> [All visitors to Singapore must meet the following entry requirements](http://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/consular_information/foreigners_visiting_singapore.html):
>
> - Valid travel document (minimum validity of 6 months at the time of departure)
> - Onward or return ticket (if applicable)
> - Entry facilities to the next destination; and
> - Sufficient funds to stay in Singapore and visa for entry into Singapore (if applicable)